# Movable Type: Weekly event calendar

Tags: movabletype

I am on Movable type 5.2

How would I create a weekly event calendar (7day) using MT tags?  I am aware of the MTCalendar tag but this tag does not support weekly dates.

I would like to create "What's going on this week" type of display.

Comment: It looks like you are talking about dates in the future, not the past.  So, where is the date of the event?  Did you add a custom field using Movable Type Pro?  Did you put a future date on an entry representing the event?  If so, which date field are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a way to do it using the standard template language, but you can probably make a very simple plugin to help you here.

Your options:

A block tag that loads the entries for this week.

A conditional tag that is true is this calendar week is the same as the entry week. (so you can use it inside the calendar tag)

A tag that set variables for the start and end timestamps, so you can compare them with entries's time.

Good luck.